# import pandas fails - File "tseries.pyx", ValueError: level must be >= 0

Tags: python, pandas

I successfully installed pandas in my venv, can see it when i do a pip list. however in my script, doing a import pandas fails
import pandas as pd
 File "/**init**.py", line 10, in 
    import pandas._tseries as lib
  File "tseries.pyx", line 14, in init pandas._tseries (pandas/src/tseries.c:106903)
ValueError: level must be >= 0
Any ideas? I dont have network access in the system so had to install pandas using a tar (did install dateutil and numpy as pre-req)

Comment: Are you sure you are running in the right python version (`2` or `3`)?

Comment: Running python 3.5- also the versions for the packages is-         numpy (1.7.1)
pandas (0.7.3)
python-dateutil (2.4.2)
pytz (2018.3)

Comment: @RafaelC do you think it could be version issue? I did download all the dependencies separately and then pip installed them one by one

Comment: Definitely looks like a version mismatch problem to me ! Ideally you should install pandas using network instead of tar